# Android:Need to set Image before to TextView

Tags: android

i need to set a image dynamically before to text view on the below mentioned code , so how to do this.?my code is below..

```
if (attchStringArray.length > 0) {                      
    LinearLayout attachemntLayout = new   LinearLayout(mainContext);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    TextView attNameView = new TextView(mainContext);
    ImageView Ivbackground= new ImageView(mainContext);
    attNameView.setText(attchStringArray[2]);
    attachemntLayout.addView(attNameView,  layoutParam);            
    attachemntLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_for_answers);
    attachmentsection.addView(attachemntLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added 2 lines in your original code. Check the lines that are preceded with comments.

EDIT: You should load the image view with some image using eg. `ImageView.setImageResource()` or `ImageView.setImageDrawable()` or `ImageView.setImageBitmap()`.

```
if (attchStringArray.length > 0) {

    LinearLayout attachemntLayout = new   LinearLayout(mainContext);

    // Changed width to WRAP_CONTENT
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam  = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    TextView attNameView = new TextView(mainContext);
    ImageView Ivbackground= new ImageView(mainContext);

    // You should put some content in the ImageView
    // ...

    attNameView.setText(attchStringArray[2]);

    // I am adding the image view before the text view
    attachemntLayout.addView(Ivbackground, layoutParam);

    attachemntLayout.addView(attNameView,  layoutParam);
    attachemntLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_for_answers);

    attachmentsection.addView(attachemntLayout);
}
```

Comment: actually i need to set iamge before to text view in tha same line..then why you set orientation vertical? and also am not getting your idea..

Comment: please convert these line with  using any image name : // I am adding the image view before the text view
    // You may need to pass a layout param that has width=WRAP_CONTENT 
    // and height=WRAP_CONTENT
    attachemntLayout.addView(Ivbackground, layoutParam);

Comment: I have edited the code. I removed the "set orientation vertical". I understood that you need it in horizontal (the default). I also changed the layout params to WIDTH=WRAP_CONTENT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `setBackgroundDrawable()` for your `TextView`

```
  yourTextView.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drwable.your_image_name);
```